# Consecutive matplotlib animation in same figure

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have an algorithm which consists of two distinct parts which I want to visualize one after another (while possibly keeping the final state of animation 1 on the screen when animation 2 starts).

I can visualize both parts individually by calling `animation.FuncAnimation` and `plt.show()`. Since both parts have set number of frames and their very own behaviour, I would like to keep their implementations apart in two different classes and then do a wrapper around them which plays them in sequence.

However, is it possible to have two (or more) animation objects to be displayed one after another in the same figure?

Many thanks,
Matt

Comment: Yes it is possible. Since you know the number of frames of the first animation, I could imagine using a timer to start the second animation could work well. A simple wrapper class could also be used. If you want to provide a [mcve] of the issue, one can easily provide an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I came up with a solution which updates only certain elements of my animator state depending on the current time step. Here is a small example illustrating this approach:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from math import sin, radians


class AnimationHandler:
    def __init__(self, ax):

        self.ax = ax

        self.lines   = [self.ax.plot([], []), self.ax.plot([], [])]
        self.colors  = ['cyan', 'red']
        self.n_steps = [360, 360]
        self.step = 0

    def init_animation(self):
        for anim_idx in [0, 1]:
            self.lines[anim_idx], = self.ax.plot([0, 10], [0, 0], c=self.colors[anim_idx], linewidth=2)
        self.ax.set_ylim([-2, 2])
        self.ax.axis('off')

        return tuple(self.lines)

    def update_slope(self, step, anim_idx):
        self.lines[anim_idx].set_data([0, 10], [0, sin(radians(step))])

    def animate(self, step):
        # animation 1
        if 0 < step < self.n_steps[0]:
            self.update_slope(step, anim_idx=0)

        # animation 2
        if self.n_steps[0] < step < sum(self.n_steps):
            self.update_slope(step - self.n_steps[0], anim_idx=1)

        return tuple(self.lines)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig, axes = plt.subplots()
    animator = AnimationHandler(ax=axes)
    my_animation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                                           animator.animate,
                                           frames=sum(animator.n_steps),
                                           interval=10,
                                           blit=True,
                                           init_func=animator.init_animation,
                                           repeat=False)

    Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
    writer = Writer(fps=24, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)
    my_animation.save('./anim_test.mp4', writer=writer)

    plt.show()
```

[image]

I used this approach to visualize/debug an algorithm which has different elements with varying runtimes. Approach is the same: You know the number of steps of each subsequence and adjust the state accordingly.

[image]