# Consecutive plot animation in same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

Following the example of [matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/random_walk.html), I want to plot a discretised Lévy path (should be expandable to a 2D or 3D setting). So, I started with a simple plot of (time, brownian path) and wanted to simulate the jumps just by "glueing together" different paths. Here is a minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


np.random.seed(19680801)

def generateRandomLines(dt, T, N):
    t = np.linspace(0,T,N)

    dX = np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(1, N)
    X = np.cumsum(dX, axis=1)

    lineData = np.vstack((t,X))

    return lineData

# Returns Line2D objects
def updateLines(num, dataLines, lines):
    for u, v in zip(lines, dataLines):
        u.set_data(v[:2, :num])
    return lines


N = 500 # Number of points
T = .5
dt = T/(N-1)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = [
        [generateRandomLines(dt, T, N),'violet'],
        [.5+generateRandomLines(dt, T, N),'violet'],
        [1+generateRandomLines(dt, T, N),'violet'],
        [1.5+generateRandomLines(dt, T, N),'violet'],
        ]

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-.5, 2.5), ylim=(-2.5, 2.5))

ax.set_xlabel('t')
ax.set_ylabel('B(t)')
ax.set_title('2D Brownian Paths')

## Create a list of line2D objects
dataLines = [dat[0] for dat in data]
lines = [ax.plot(dat[0][0, 0:1], dat[0][1, 0:1], color=dat[1])[0] for dat in data]

## Create the animation object
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updateLines, N+1, fargs=(dataLines, lines),
                               interval=20, repeat=False, blit=False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

For now, the four paths generated in `data` are plotted/animated simultaneously. But I want the animated objects to be displayed one after another in the same figure.

Obviously, I do not really understand how to treat the lines and dataLines objects in the function

```
def updateLines(num, dataLines, lines):
    for u, v in zip(lines, dataLines):
        u.set_data(v[:2, :num])
    return lines
```

Similar to [question ("Consecutive matplotlib animation in same figure")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46982193/consecutive-matplotlib-animation-in-same-figure) I tried to iterate over the `lines` object which produces an error with zip ("argument #1 must support iteration").

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Redefining `updateLines` in the following way solves my problem

```
# Returns Line2D objects
def updateLines(num, dataLines, lines):
    if num < N:
        lines[0].set_data(dataLines[0][:2, :num])
    elif num < N * 2:
        lines[1].set_data(dataLines[1][:2, :num-N])
    elif num < N * 3:
        lines[2].set_data(dataLines[2][:2, :num-2*N])
    else:
        lines[3].set_data(dataLines[3][:2, :num-3*N])
    return lines
```

and increasing the number of points appropriately to `N * 4 + 1`

```
## Create the animation object
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updateLines, N * 4 + 1, fargs=(dataLines, lines),
                               interval=20, repeat=False, blit=False)
```